# How do I make the background responsive and keep content centered?

Tags: html, css

I have looked everywhere and nothing seems to resolve my problem. This is the HTML which just contains a plain HTML login form:

```css
body{
  background-image:url(http://i63.tinypic.com/raytyu.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.h1Tag{
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 150%;

  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #b2e0ef;
}
li{
  float: center;
}
a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #3399ff;
  text-decoration:none;
}
li a{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight:bold;
}
/*-----------LOGIN FORM CSS-------------------*/
#login_form{
  background-color: rgba(178,224,239,0.6);
  position:center;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 550px;
  margin-right: 550px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  border-radius:3px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #fff;
}
.login_form{
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="login_form">
  <div class="h1Tag">
    <h1>MyGarden</h1>  
  </div>
  <div class="login_form">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email address"><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Log In</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, when I launch this in Google Chrome, the background and login form are correctly placed on a full maximised Chrome window. However when I resize the window, the background decreases and remains in the top left corner of the window while the login form is on the right hand side of the page.

The login box div is under `#login_form` and the background is in the body CSS class.

Comment: Please provide working Snippet for better understand your issue

Comment: Why do you use absolute positions?

Comment: It keeps the login form stable.

Comment: can you provide a JS fiddle please?

Comment: You should be able to view it now that I have added the background image. There is not JS for this yet.

Comment: for the background issue: set html height to 100%; For login: you have hardcoded margins (left and right), set it to auto and it will be centered

Comment: forgot to say: for the margin: auto to work it does need a relative position...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/3j3wcypx/

in your html I just add two `divs` as a parents of your `.login_form` and gave the `background` to the super `parent`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="login">
    <div id="login_form">
      <div class="h1Tag">
        <h1>MyGarden</h1>       
      </div>
      <div class="login_form">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email address"><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Log In</button>
      </div>
    </div>  

  </div>  
</div>
```

and the css I removed the margin from `#login_form` and gave it `display:inline-block` so it will be centered horizontally and its parent `.login` `diplay:table-cell` to be centered vertically :

```
.container{
  background-image:url(http://i63.tinypic.com/raytyu.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:table;
}
.login{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
}
.h1Tag{
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 150%;

  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #b2e0ef;
}
li{
  float: center;
}
a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #3399ff;
  text-decoration:none;
}
li a{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight:bold;
}
/*-----------LOGIN FORM CSS-------------------*/
#login_form{
  background-color: rgba(178,224,239,0.6);
  position:center;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius:3px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #fff;
  display:inline-block;
}
.login_form{
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmed. Can you explain the position and display attributes in the container css?

Comment: just to show things can be done in different ways, a bit the same solution without extra divs: https://jsfiddle.net/999jbg66/

Answer (score 3):

Edit the following 2 css stuff,

set the background for html instead of body , 
set the height to 100%,
if you set background-size: 100% 100%; then it will stretch and occupy 100% of screen
if you set background-size: cover then enough part of image will be shown ,not whole part of image, will not stretch image 
1.

```
html {
    background-image: url(http://i63.tinypic.com/raytyu.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

don't set margins in px ,set in %
set the width of the box and remove px margins
remove position , here no need

2.

```
#login_form {
    background-color: rgba(178,224,239,0.6);
    position: center;
    padding: 20px;
    /* position: absolute; */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    width: 235px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below css, Link to the codepen in the last try changing image url if it doesn't work

```
    body{
  background:url(https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/01/22/19/44/flower-garden-250016_960_720.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size:cover;
}
.h1Tag{
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 150%;

  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #b2e0ef;
}
li{
  float: center;
}
a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #3399ff;
  text-decoration:none;
}
li a{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight:bold;
}
/*-----------LOGIN FORM CSS-------------------*/
#login_form{
  background-color: rgba(178,224,239,0.6);
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  border-radius:3px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #fff;
  width:250px;
}
.login_form{
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MeYOBx

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#login_form {
background-color: rgba(178,224,239,0.6);
position: center;
padding: 20px;
/* position: absolute; */
/* margin-right: 550px; */
/* margin-top: 150px; */
border-radius: 3px;
border: 1px solid;
border-color: #fff;
margin: 150px auto;
width: 236px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rohit - I was not familiar with margin values. However when viewing this on a mobile device, there is a lot of white space - is this preventable?

Comment: there's a little error in this code - position: center is not valid css